# Uso de dplyr y summarise con valores perdidos

Tags: r

Tengo una conjunto de países en los que observo la tasa de suicidio en el tiempo. Quiero obtener el promedio de las tasas de suicidio por países. He tratado de emplear este código, y para ello como hay valores perdidos, he incluido también na.rm, pero me da los resultados, como podría hacer

```
Suicide.avg.per.country <- suicidedata %>% group_by(country_name) %>% summarise(AVG_SUICIDE = mean(suicidedata$suicidetotal), na.rm=T)

A tibble: 22 × 3
     country_name AVG_SUICIDE na.rm
            <chr>       <lgl> <lgl>
1            MKD*          NA  TRUE
2         Armenia          NA  TRUE
3      Azerbaijan          NA  TRUE
4         Belarus          NA  TRUE
5        Bulgaria          NA  TRUE
6  Czech Republic          NA  TRUE
7         Estonia          NA  TRUE
8         Georgia          NA  TRUE
9         Hungary          NA  TRUE
10     Kazakhstan          NA  TRUE
# ... with 12 more rows
```

He probado sin embargo con tapply y obtengo los resultados

```
 tapply(suicidedata$suicidetotal, suicidedata$country_name, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
               MKD*             Armenia          Azerbaijan 
           4.996500            2.861031            1.767627 
            Belarus            Bulgaria      Czech Republic 
          46.165000           11.471000           16.550500 
            Estonia             Georgia             Hungary 
          38.774500            3.543044           30.316000 
         Kazakhstan          Kyrgyzstan              Latvia 
          40.884500           17.784500           41.274500 
          Lithuania              Poland Republic of Moldova 
          59.663500           21.236111           25.288500 
            Romania  Russian Federation            Slovakia 
          15.783500           48.499000           17.968889 
           Slovenia          Tajikistan             Ukraine 
          26.684500            4.652000           34.449500 
         Uzbekistan 
           9.869333
```

Gracias por anticipado
Antonio

Comment: Hola @Antonio, te sugiero que trates siempre de presentar un [ejemplo  mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Para tu pregunta sería bueno que aportes un ejemplo mínimo de `suicidedata` o al menos indiques el enlace dónde recuperar dichos datos.

Comment: Me parece que tu pregunta se responde con esto
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26665501/2374161

Answer (score 0):

Un posible problema es que los datos no estén siendo considerados como numéricos, pero eso se resuelve rápidamente:

```
tapply(as.numeric(suicidedata$suicidetotal), suicidedata$country_name, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

También te recuerdo una forma más sencilla usando `aggregate`

```
aggregate(as.numeric(suicidetotal) ~ country_name, suicidedata, mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

creo que el problema es que `na.rm=T` debe ser pasado como parámetro de la funcion `mean`.

Es decir en vez de:

```
Suicide.avg.per.country <- suicidedata %>% group_by(country_name) %>% 
summarise(AVG_SUICIDE = mean(suicidedata$suicidetotal), na.rm=T)
```

poner:

```
Suicide.avg.per.country <- suicidedata %>% group_by(country_name) %>% 
summarise(AVG_SUICIDE = mean(suicidedata$suicidetotal, na.rm=T))
```